# Virtual machine vmnet 8 not found

Tags: virtual-machine

When I am trying to connect internet my virtual machine then It shows couldn't connect vmnet8 not found

Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet8'. More information can be found in the vmware.log file. Failed to connect virtual device 'Ethernet0'.
please tell me solution for this .

I tried many solution  that are present on internet but non of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same problem ,
I  firstly uninstalled vm ware and the installed it again ,
It worked fine for me